# Linked List issues C++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

So I'm having a couple of issues with linked lists in C++. When I try to make a new list,
the most recent node is the only one in the list. I'm thinking it's an issue with the
pointer to the node after where it's being inserted, but I'm not sure as I'm new to C++
and linked lists. Any assistance is gladly welcome!

```
    // Nodes struct is declared, "int value" is data stored;
    void Class::addNode(int val)
    {
        nodeptr temp;
        temp = new node;
        temp->value = val;
        temp->next = nullptr;
        nodeptr crt, prv;
        for (prv = nullptr, crt = headPtr; /* pointer to first node */ 
        crt != nullptr && temp->value < crt->value; prv->next = crt, crt = crt->next)
        {
            // nothing because it's just to get crt and prv in position
        }
        if (crt = headPtr)
        {
            headPtr = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            prv->next = temp;
        }
        temp->next = crt;
    }
```

Comment: `if (crt = headPtr)` should be `if (crt == headPtr)`

Comment: `ptr` points to `nullptr` when you dereference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block:

```
if (crt = headPtr)
    {
        headPtr = temp;
    }
```

You are setting crt to headPtr instead of checking if it is equal to headPtr so it is always falling into the condition and setting headPtr to remp.  Should be like this:

```
if (crt == headPtr)
    {
        headPtr = temp;
    }
```